# Constant(ish) distance between multiple objects

Tags: sensor, distance, tracking

I’m working on a project where I need to be able to represent the positions of multiple, slow moving objects (between 5 and 30) on an X/Y plane (with a size of about 25m X 25m) in an outdoor environment, subject to weather conditions and consistent, very loud, noises. Accuracy to about a few inches will be needed.

Generally, the objects won’t be any further than 1 - 2 meters apart at any given moment. The sensors and transmitters will be placed in an external location and therefore shouldn’t have any limitations due to material interference. Size is a limiting factor, preferably something smaller than around a deck of cards.

I know this is a lot of info, but I wanted to be as thorough as possible.

What do you think would be the best approach to an efficient and affordable solution?

Comment: You’ve mixed metric and imperial measurements! GNSS might be a solution, especially when using a local source of corrections.

Comment: You need to give max speed - and ideally speed profile.

Comment: Also, target sizes (width and height), materials and surface finish, and target cost.

Comment: `I know this is a lot of info` ... not much, really ... for example, what is the orientation of the XY plane relative to horizontal? ... are these objects crawling on a surface?

Comment: Sounds interesting!  What sort of objects are they?  Can you put things on top of the objects?  Do you have a good aerial view of the whole 25m square?  How long do you have to track them for?  Can we prepare them arbitrarily?  "slow moving" -- what's that in numbers?